# Creating XML in C# lists

Tags: c#, xml

i am trying to create XML using C# and i am aware of the traditional method of creating XML such as

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, doc.DocumentElement);

XmlElement element1 = doc.CreateElement("", "body", "");
doc.AppendChild(element1);

XmlElement element2 = doc.CreateElement("", "type", "");
element1.AppendChild(element2);

XmlElement element3 = doc.CreateElement("", "Numbers", "");
element2.AppendChild(element3);
XmlElement element4 = doc.CreateElement("", "one", "");
XmlText text1 = doc.CreateTextNode("1");
element4.AppendChild(text1);
element3.AppendChild(element4);
```

now i want the element to be list of XMLelement and the text as a list of XMLtext. i am having a problem to append the childnodes of the element while using the list.

```
 List<XmlElement> elements = new List<XmlElement>() {doc.CreateElement("", "type" ,""),doc.CreateElement("", "numbers" ,""),doc.CreateElement("", "one" ,""),doc.CreateElement("", "two" ,"") };

foreach (var elementss in elements)
{
    elementss.AppendChild(elementss);
    Console.WriteLine(elementss.ChildNodes);
}
```

please clarify whether i am right in implementing lists in this scenario..???
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Linq to XML, which is the name of what you are looking for, have a way of creating XML documents which can be better formatted than the older System.Xml way.

Maybe something like this could be easier to use:

```
var doc = new XElement("body", 
                  new XElement("type"),
                      new XElement("Numbers",
                          new XElement("one", 1)
                      )
                  )
              );
```

Comment: thanks..i knew this earlier..i am trying to find an alternative to the conventional XmlDocument method..

Comment: Linq to XML is that alternative, unless you want to go with serialization.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not quite sure why you add an item to itself in

```
elementss.AppendChild(elementss);
```

but, instead of adding new elements to the list, add the ones that exist:

```
foreach(XmlNode elements in doc.ChildNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elementss.ChildNodes);
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error regarding the typecasting of variable to XMLNodeList